# Can't install app via ad-hoc URL. Gives: This application is missing the initialODRSize key in the log

Tags: ios, iphone, installation, ad-hoc-distribution

All of a sudden today I (and others) can't download my app via an ad-hoc link. I've rebuild it just like I did every time, and uploaded it to my dropbox public folder.

Now when people try to download it, it gives a popup that it can't download it at this moment. And in the log it says:

```
 This application is missing the initialODRSize key
```

Any thoughts what this might be?

Comment: see this once https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7372190?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I saw these discussions, but it had nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently after 2 hours this has resolved itself and the app is re-installing again (on my and someone else's phone).

So if anyone bumps into this, it might just be a problem with an apple server being down.